# How to paste multiline text in pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

Every time I try to copy and paste something on my Pycharm editor it all paste it in single line. How to automatically paste in multiline?[1]

This is what I copied:

```
[{"DateObserved":"2020-06-12 ","HourObserved":23,"LocalTimeZone":"EST","ReportingArea":"Central New York Region","StateCode":"NY","Latitude":42.8049,"Longitude":-76.3589,"ParameterName":"O3","AQI":35,"Category":{"Number":1,"Name":"Good"}},{"DateObserved":"2020-06-12 ","HourObserved":23,"LocalTimeZone":"EST","ReportingArea":"Central New York Region","StateCode":"NY","Latitude":42.8049,"Longitude":-76.3589,"ParameterName":"PM2.5","AQI":0,"Category":{"Number":1,"Name":"Good"}}]
```

and this all got pasted in a single line on my Pycharm editor. Can anybody help with that, its pretty hard to read all this info on a single line?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you didn't copy anything containing newlines as you can see better after my edit (See the side-by-side-markdown diff so you can see that I didn't remove any line breaks).

If you just copy everything as a single line, PyCharm won't be able to split it into multiple lines (except with auto-format maybe).

As you haven't said how you copied the input, I can't say what exactly is wrong.

However, it seems like you copied something from a program that didn't display the text correctly so that you couldn't copy it correctly.

Another possibility is that the IDE interprets line breaks differently.

For example, windows uses CRLF(carriage return+line feed) as a line seperator while linux uses LF only.

If your file contains only LF line breaks and PyCharm is configured to use CRLF like breaks, it is possible that it ignores them because of that.

You can change that behaviour at the bottom of your file in PyCharm (button with CR/CRLF/LF).